# How do I create interface methods using .tlb types in VS C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com, atl, typelib

Background:

1. The .TLB file contains interfaces written in language 'X'. I don't have .h, .idl, .tlh, or any other header files - just the .TLB file.  Language 'X' does not export compatible .h, .idl, etc.
2. I use the VS wizard to add an ATL simple object to my ATL project.

I want to add a method to the interface of my simple ATL object that uses one of the .TLB defined types for a parameter.

```
// Something like the following in the .idl file:
interface ISomeInterface : IUnknown {
   HRESULT SomeMethod([in] ITypeFromTLB* aVal); // ITypeFromTLB declared in .TLB file.
};
```

How can I do this?  I'm hoping for a wizard, or a line in the .idl interface declaration that would bring in the .tlb information.  midl's include (no .tlb), import (no tlb), and importlib (library only) don't seem to provide a solution (I *need* proxy/stub to be working, so I cannot put this inside the library declaration with the importlib command).

Answer (score 3):

Use [#import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(VS.71).aspx) in cpp/h to bring TLB interfaces to your namespace.

Comment: This isn't available in the midl compiler.

Comment: This is a directive of the C/C++ compiler, not MIDL compiler. Put it right after your #include's

Comment: I need to bring in the information in my IDL file so that I can declare a new interface.  #import only brings the information into my .h and .cpp files.

Comment: Which interface proxy/stub is not working when you use importlib?

Comment: The IDL file won't compile.  The ITypeFromTLB type is undeclared.  It exists in the .tlb file, but I can't figure out how to get it into the .idl file as specified in my original post.

Comment: Then why is `importlib` not working? Try `importlib("C:\\Path\\To\\Your.tlb");` in `library` scope before using `ITypeFromTLB` in methods signature.

Comment: importlib can only be used *inside* a library declaration.  In order for proxy/stub stuff to work, the ISomeInterface declaration must be *before* the library declaration.  importlib *cannot* be used due to limitations in its capabilities.

Comment: I see. Did you try changing the "offending" params from custom interfaces to `IUnknown`? Do you need these params to be strongly typed?

Comment: Yes - I need these interfaces to be strongly typed.

Comment: As a last resort use `OleView` to extract just the needed interfaces in an .idl from the typelib, then import this .idl file.

Comment: Yes, I've used this method. However, it's a manual process (prone to human error), and the idl is not always C++ friendly for some reason, requiring substantial human editing.  Is it possible that Microsoft has overlooked a functionality so basic as this?  This seems like a basic task to me, and should be easy!

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio command line do oleview. Then File -> View Type Lib, give it full path to your foo.tlb. Now in ITypeLib Viewer do File -> Save As .. and you can export all 3 (.h, .idl, .c) from there.

Comment: note that you need to run `oleview` as admin for this to work