# Importing interfaces in IDL from an external type library

Tags: atl, idl, midl, typelib

I have two type libraries with COM interfaces that I wrote using ATL and Microsoft's IDL. I would like an interface in one library to inherit from an interface in the other.

Essentially, I would like to do the same thing that Steven described at [How do I create interface methods using .tlb types in VS C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473595/how-do-i-create-interface-methods-using-tlb-types-in-vs-c). The only person who answered him did not seem to understand the question.

Here's what I'd like to do, in code:

---

### SomeLibrary DLL/TLB

#### ISomeInterface.idl

```
interface ISomeInterface : IDispatch { ... };
```

#### SomeLibrary.idl

```
import "ISomeInterface.idl";

library SomeLibrary
{
    interface ISomeInterface;
};
```

---

### SomeOtherLibrary DLL/TLB

#### ISomeOtherInterface.idl

```
// What do I put here so that the MIDL compiler knows
// what to do when it encounters the ISomeInterface type?

interface ISomeOtherInterface : ISomeInterface { ... };
```

#### SomeOtherLibrary.idl

```
import "ISomeOtherInterface.idl";

library SomeOtherLibrary
{
    interface ISomeOtherInterface;
};
```

---

The MIDL [`import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367047%28VS.85%29.aspx) directive only works when importing IDL files, and I only have a DLL and TLB. I can't use [`importlib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367050%28VS.85%29.aspx) because that only works within a [`library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367069%28VS.85%29.aspx) definition. The MIDL compiler doesn't understand Microsoft's C++ [`import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2de1a8a.aspx), [`importidl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x95tb0e.aspx), and [`importlib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/febxcfsz.aspx) attributes.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to introduce a manual step, you can open the tlb in oleview and get a generated .idl file that way. oleview.exe lives in the bin dir of the Windows SDK, eg

```
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\oleview.exe
```